# Multiple issues running grunt.cmd on windows

Tags: windows, node.js, gruntjs

I had to modify grunt.cmd because the path for my system was very wrong:

Originally:

`%~dp0\Application Data\npm\node_modules\grunt`

Which would print:

`\\dacwnas\Profiles\<user>\Application Data\npm\Application Data\npm\node_modules\grunt`

Running grunt.cmd would throw a cannot find module error. Changing it to `%~dp0\node_modules\grunt"` removes the error.

But, running `grunt.cmd --version` in windows outputs nothing. It simply pauses for a moment and returns to a blank command line.

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit, and the command line is run as administrator

Comment: How did you install grunt? `npm install -g grunt`? The `grunt.cmd` file is automatically generated by npm and shouldn't be edited. Try re-installing grunt with npm after correcting your system path.

Comment: @KyleRobinsonYoung: if npm put the wrong path there the first time I don't see why it would do any better if he reinstalls.  Looks to me like a bug in Grunt exhibited when the user has a redirected Application Data folder.

Comment: How is it a bug in Grunt when the `grunt.cmd` file is automatically generated by npm? The issue he is indicating, it's likely an issue for all his globally installed node modules and not just Grunt.If he corrects his system path and reinstalls, npm should generate a correct grunt.cmd file.

Comment: I imagine that the remote profile is what is causing the issue. I could install npm and node manually. I haven't tried any other packages, but I assume that I'd run into similar issues.

Comment: @KyleRobinsonYoung: How does npm use %PATH% when creating grunt.cmd? I don't see the connection. It looks to me as if it is using %APPDATA% or equivalent and not coping when it doesn't start with a drive letter. (However, I probably should have said a bug in npm rather than a bug in Grunt.)

Comment: Can you provide more information? For me grunt works perfectly on windows. Did you install grunt-cli globally as your question suggest?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally pressed enter. :(

Comment: The first path is correct, this is the place where global modules are installed. Can you show us output of <code>npm ls -g</code> and <code>grunt -v</code> with he first path?

Comment: Sadly, I no longer run Windows for development. I might fire up my windows box to try this again.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should have the `grunt-cli` package installed globally:

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

Next, make sure you have `grunt` installed in your project folder.

You can do this by:

- Making sure `grunt` is part of your `package.json` and run: `npm install`
- Going to your project folder and just `npm install grunt`

After this, you shouldn't have any trouble running Grunt.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install grunt-cli?

My grunt.cmd content looks like that:

```
:: Created by npm, please don't edit manually.
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt" %*
) ELSE (
   node  "%~dp0\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt" %*
)
```